# How can I pass a bash variable to a javascript expression flag of a java application?

Tags: javascript, java, bash

I'm calling a java application with

```
java -jar app.jar -e 'javascript expression'
```

Where within -e is javascript code that performs some function. However, I want to wrap this in a loop that defines a parameter within that -e flag.

The only way I can think to do this is to define a bash variable within the loop and pass it to the JS expression.

I do not know how to do this. Surrounding the variable in double quotes when inserting into the JS expression did not work.

Comment: Show what you tried; the right answer shouldn't be much different.

Comment: Is the bash variable exported as an environment variable? If no, then you need to give it as argument to the Java program. Either way, your Java program has to then give it to the JavaScript as a binding variable.

Comment: The solution was to wrap the javascript expression in double quotes and surround the variable in escaped double quotes like \"${variable}\"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop

```
#!/bin/bash
# do java stuff `$ do_java_stuff javascript_expression javascript_expression`
for exp; do
    java -jar app.jar -e $exp
done
```

```
$ do_java_stuff javascript_expression javascript_expression
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to wrap the javascript expression in double quotes and surround the variable in escaped double quotes like \"${variable}\"

Comment: That's almost certainly not what you want to do.